# What is the best way to execute nodejs app on a server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

Is there a panel for run node app?
Just have to run it on the server?
Set everything up manually?
Manual installation xngin ,apache ,mongodb , ...
Manual Server Configuration.
Is there a similar panel Vesta?

Answer (score 0):

There are services like Heroku or Digital Ocean where you can get a node server up without having to do a lot of setup (i.e. not touching apache or nginx etc.). I think that's what you're looking for.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction

Comment: But I do not want to use them.
I want to do this on my server.
We do not have the ability to buy from those sites. Our country is sanctioned.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly after creating a social network in React, PHP and mysql I would recommend uploading the build files to a conventional hosting provider. Not only is it cheaper in the long run but it is probably easier to use. You can do this by typing "npm run build" then uploading the files in the build folder to your hosts main directory either manually or by ftp in atom etc... but it's basically depends on your work flow and whether or not you have a dev ops guy on your team.

Comment: I work with express, socket.io.
Problem was created when executing this command

Comment: npm ERR! missing script: build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MRZ\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-15T19_56_15_471Z-debug.log

Comment: Check the log then check stackoverflow haha